# A Parameter is missing. [Parameter ordinal = 1]

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

So i've been making a simple c# win forms application for something league of legends related and i've been using a .SDF Database which I'm very new with.

When trying to make a search option I came across this error:

> A Parameter is missing. [Parameter ordinal = 1]

Here is my Code: (I did Add the Parameter to the command.)

```
public DataTable GetDataTableSummoners(string Summoner, string Champion)
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Summoner";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Summoner))
        {
            SqlCeParameter param = new SqlCeParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@Summoner";
            param.Value = Summoner;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Summoner WHERE name = @Summoner";
        }
        var adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn);
        adapter.Fill(t);
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: is conn a globally defined SqlConnection?

Comment: Well yes its globally defined :)

Comment: There's no need to change the title to SOLVED. When you accept an answer it is marked as solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're adding the parameter to the command - but then you're ignoring the command itself here:

```
var adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn);
```

You're *only* passing in the command text, which doesn't include the parameter. You want:

```
var adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
```

(I'd also suggest using a `using` statement for the command, and changing your method parameter names to follow .NET naming conventions. Oh, and you don't appear to be using the champion parameter...)

Oh, and you can add a parameter much more easily like this (also specifying the type, which is a good idea):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Summoner", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Summoner;
```

Comment: I see, Well I made it work with the suggestions you made, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In DataAdapter Pass complete Command Object not only Command Text

`var adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd, conn);`

or You can add parameter like this

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

 }
```

or you can use `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` also.